# Find the timestamp closer to the ones in the file

Tags: python

I've done a script in which, given a timestamps, it looks for the same timestamp in a file which contains different timestamps written in a different format.

This is the code:

```
import pytz, datetime
import re
from dateutil.parser import parse

local = pytz.timezone ("Europe/Zurich")
naive = datetime.datetime.strptime ("2018-9-13 12:46:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
local_dt = local.localize(naive, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print 'utc_dt = ', utc_dt

utc_fileFormat=utc_dt.isoformat()
print 'utc_dt.isoformat() = ', utc_fileFormat

string=parse(utc_fileFormat)
print string

new_string=string.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
if new_string.endswith('+00:00'):
    new_string = new_string[:-6]
print new_string

with open('fill_7151_B1_timestamps.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if new_string in line:
            print line
file.close()
```

Now what I'd like to do is: if I give a timestamp that doesn't correspond exactly to the ones in the file, I have to find the closer one.

Just to have an idea of the data in the file, they are like these:

```
0 2018-07-30T15:20:36.524281125
1 2018-07-30T15:21:12.821653375
2 2018-07-30T15:21:29.271170975
3 2018-07-30T15:21:30.381507275
4 2018-07-30T16:13:05.816863525
5 2018-07-30T16:13:06.958256975
6 2018-07-30T16:13:08.082365950
7 2018-07-30T16:13:09.221720400
8 2018-07-30T16:13:10.359005400
9 2018-07-30T16:13:11.487593100
10 2018-07-30T16:13:12.626307750
```

Can anyone help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand the question, but can you subtract the input timestamp by all timestamps in the file and take the one closest to zero?

Comment: Yes for sure, but the problem is that the timestamps in the file are strings, and I don't know if in python it's possible to subtract strings